# An idiom meaning getting pushed back or getting bullied or a similar meaning and containing the word "foot"?

Tags: idiom-request

An idiom meaning getting pushed back or getting bullied or a similar meaning and containing the word "foot"?

Is there a meaning like that? Standing on a single foot? It's something like it, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the phrase you remember is "on the back foot" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-back-foot-put-someone-on-the-back-foot

It means to be threatened and so acting defensively. The metaphor comes from boxing (from when a boxer leans back putting their weight on the hind foot as a defensive position)

> Messi put Liverpool on the back foot by scoring twice in the first twenty-minutes

Not really "bullied" but certainly "pushed back".